# How to remove percentage % sign from redirect form action url

Tags: php, html, apache

I am facing issue, While my form action URL redirect -

```
<form action="https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query='+ result.domain" id="search-form" method="POST">
```

Output -

```
https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=%27+%20result.domain
```

It's taking `%` percentage sign in URL,  It should be as it is like form action url.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate some string?

Comment: Nop,  See Riccardo Sibani answer, there are space and single quote.

Comment: I know that, I am the one who upvoted that answer. `'+` made me think so. And if it solved the problem accept the answer

Comment: Yes , it's done bro, Thanks for the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The % sign in the url is nothing else than the HTML URL Encoding https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

When you see the %20 or %27 you are respectively saying that there is a space or a single quote in the query parameter.

If you don't want them, you should replace the space and the single quote from your code.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, Riccardo,  it's working there is space and single quote.

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned in above question action URL

[https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query='+ result.domain](https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query='%20%20result.domain)

consists of special characters and upon opening such URL in a web browser special params are encoded i.e URL encoding.

According to documentation as mentioned in [w3schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
>   to be converted into a valid ASCII format. URL encoding replaces
>   unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong wiht the % sign? %27 is just what the url encoding for char ' and %20 for char "space".

You can find more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

The real question is: are you sure that you need query='+ result.domain in the url? my guess (just a guess...) is that you are using some template engine and you want something similar to query={{ result.domain }}